# Jcontrol equivalent in Corretto 8

Tags: java, corretto

We used to use a java application on our linux desktops that used openjdk 1.7.  If I needed to troubleshoot a problem, I'd launch "jcontrol" and enable debug and trace.  This would spit out a java/trace log I could read.  My company has now switched to a corretto 8 application and "jcontrol" doesn't seem to exist any longer.  Can you tell me how I would get some debug/trace logs generated for my java application now?

Comment: [jconsole](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1165758/where-is-controlpanel-or-jcontrol-for-openjdk-1-8-222) maybe?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with jcontrol, but what you're describing sounds like [jconsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html).

Comment: This answer might add more context on why jcontrol doesn't work anymore with corretto 8 application https://askubuntu.com/a/1165769. @earthling-amzn might be a good idea to consider adding that information to your answer.